# jQuery validation , submit handler, and submit form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, .post

I am having some problems on executing the following code.

1. The code submits but it doesnt do anything, it comes back to the same screen, it seems that the values of the form have been not submited.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#signin_form").validate({
             debug: false,
             rules: {
              ///
              },
              messages: {
              ///
              },
             submitHandler: function(form) { 
                 var result;

           $.post('test.php', $('#signin_form').serialize(),    function(data){
               result = $.parseJSON(data);

               if (result.flag == 'false'){
                   $('#results').show()
               }
           })
           .success(function(data){
               if (result.flag == 'true'){
                   form.submit();
               }

           }, 'json');

          }
      });
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. If I change the code to the following, it works and it takes me to the proper screen, but i need to validate, a captcha code, i am not sure if it is the right place to do it, i tried to use beforeSubmit but then the captcha is not validated.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#signin_form").validate({
             debug: false,
             rules: {
              ///
              },
              messages: {
              ///
              },
             submitHandler: function(form) { 
                 form.submit();


          }
      });
   });
   </script>
   ```

There is something about the $.post that i dont underestand... and doesnt submit the information.

Does anyone know what it could be?
thanks!

Comment: If you need to validate a captcha, you should do that with a remote validation method, you don't need to change how the form submits. I think there's an example of captcha on the plugin's documentation page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to change how the `form` submits, in this case, for validating the captcha, use `remote` function from `jquery.validate`.

There are some problems around the `remote` usage with `jquery.validate`. Check if you did the following:

**1)** Make sure you are using *jQuery* version **1.6.1** and above only.

**2)** Use the "synchronous" option for remote execution (default being asynchronous) and to do this set `async` argument to false.

---

### Example of usage:

Suppose this is my form...

***HTML:***

Add `id` and `name` attributes to all the form elements or just the captcha *(this one must have both).*

```
<form id="signin_form" action="save.php" method="POST">
  Enter captcha: O1S2C3A4R
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

***jQuery:***

Add `type`, `async` and `data` arguments. This last argument passes the captcha value to **check.php** file and that's why that element needs the `id` attribute. Then you are able to use this selector `$('#captcha')`.

*(For me this is better but you can also call the element by name using other selector type)*

Just to know, you need to also define an error message for the `remote`, in this case I used *Invalid captcha*.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#signin_form").validate({
        rules: {
            captcha: {
                required: true,
                remote: { 
                    url:"check.php",
                    type:"post",
                    async:false,
                    data: {
                        /* this is the name of the post parameter that PHP will use: $_POST['captcha'] */
                        captcha: function() {
                            return $.trim($("#captcha").val());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            captcha: {
                required: "*",
                remote: "Invalid captcha"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

***PHP: check.php***

At this point it is important to use `"true"` or `"false"` as ***string*** to let know the `jquery.validation` plugin if the captcha is valid or not. In this case, if captcha is equals to ***O1S2C3A4R*** then is valid and, at client side, you will look that the `submit` will process the `form` to `save.php` file specified in the html `form` `action` attribute.

```
<?php

    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

    if($captcha == "O1S2C3A4R"){
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }

?>
```

---

Doing this way, you can validate the whole `form` without problems and also check the captcha value remotely without altering plugin functionality.

Also you can test all this code together and look that it works :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmmm... yeah this looks amazing, and sort of it works... the only problem is that it doesnt recognize that the response from check.php is true, and then it doesnt submit... in check.php i have  
if (!$resp->is_valid) { 
   $response = 'false'; 
  }
  else{ 
   $response = 'true'; 
  }
echo json_encode($response);

Comment: @MariaZ No problem, I am here to help :-) let me test something and I will update my answer

Comment: @MariaZ LOL, check my edited post, it works now, I forgot to specify you some details :-)

Comment: Thanks very much Oscar, I will test... I just dont see it on my code... yet... so I will try this but thank soo much for your explanation it really helps me underestand better this matter, I will let you know how it goes...

Comment: Hi this code definitly works, well... I just found out that my problems has to do with something with the recaptcha that i am using, for some strange reason this code  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]); just doesnt let the script work..., anyways i am going to mark your answer as the right one... because it is very informative... thanks!

Comment: @MariaZ that seems to be another problem fron server side, try to make some debug in your php file or echo some values step by step and you will know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#signin_form").validate({
            rules: {
                captcha: {
                    remote: {
                        url: "remote.php"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                captcha: {
                    remote: "Please enter the text in the captcha."
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML form:

```
<form id="signin_form">
    <input type="text" name="captcha">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$response = $_GET['captcha']; 
$answer  = 'captcha_answer';

if($response==$answer){
    echo 'true'; 
} else {
    echo 'false'; 
}
```

Sorry for shoving this part into an answer -- I'm not allowed to comment:

Keep in mind that setting the 'async' parameter to false will lock up your page until you get a response, which might not be what you want. The validation library should block normal form submission if it's waiting on a response for remote validation, at least in newer versions (I'm using jQuery 1.7.2  and Validation 1.10.0).

IIRC the jQuery Validate library will treat anything other than the exact string "true" as being an error. This can be used to pass different custom messages depending on the reason for rejection. json_encode adds extra quotation marks that cause jQuery Validate to see it as a custom error message.

Comment: Thanks, I just dont underestand what is captcha_id ?

Comment: It's just an example of how to pass information from other fields in the form, if you need them (since you serialized the whole form in your example). If you don't need any fields except the captcha field, you can take out the data parameter entirely.

Comment: hmm I dont know what i am doing but i just get the response "false" and  nothings happens... this is in an error box, I dont underestand, so data, I am not really sure what is doing sorry....  Thanks!

Comment: OK, I have removed the "data" parts of my answer to make it a little clearer. (The simplified answer is also tested and working.)

Comment: When you say that "false" shows up in an error box, do you mean that it shows up where the form errors are supposed to show up (usually next to the field), or that it shows up in an alert or jQuery dialog box? If "false" is showing up next to the field, that means the Validator plugin is interpreting your "false" as a custom error message. If you're still using json_encode, take those function calls out and just echo the strings. If you mean an alert or jQuery dialog box, then I'm not quite sure. There's nothing that I can see that would cause an alert or jQuery dialog to pop up.

Comment: cool thanks so much for taking the time to help, I will check this... I just had to set up all my computer again... so I will go trough these responses... slowly...

Comment: thanks so much I find your answer very informative, it is just I received similar answer a little bit before.. thanks!

Comment: NP, Maria, glad I could be of some help. Oscar, are you serious? My answer was up before you first edited (when you only had a small snippet of javascript), and my edit only removed the data parameter and a couple lines of related code. You know that people can see the full edit history of each answer by clicking on the date, right? Unfounded accusations only make you look bad.